# Is there a font picker tool to use it in user input form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking for a font picker tool to use in my web project which should allow users to choose any of the fonts listed. I have created a small code with radio button, which actually works:

```
<label style="font-family: Courier;">
    <input type="radio" name="font" value="Courier" />Courier</label>
<label style="font-family: Verdana;">
    <input type="radio" name="font" value="Verdana" />Verdana</label>
<label style="font-family: Arial;">
    <input type="radio" name="font" value="Arial" />Arial</label>
<label style="font-family: Papyrus;">
    <input type="radio" name="font" value="Papyrus" />Papyrus</label>
<label style="font-family: Monotype Corsiva;">
    <input type="radio" name="font" value="Monotype Corsiva" />Monotype Corsiva</label>
```

I need to categorise these fonts before displaying. This can be done by using two main radio buttons "font1" and "font2". When the user checks the "font1" radio button some fonts should be displayed and when user checks "font1" radio button some other fonts should be displayed. Is there a way to do this?

OR

Alternative solution for this could be creating fonts database similar to flametext and cooltext.com. Is there any way to design this type of font picker tool?

---

I have used your code but still its not working it will just create groups but does not hide "subradio" button all the radio button are displyed in a table ,thats it.... but its not hiding.. i guess the function is not working...

```
<a href="#" id="fonts_group_1b">Show font group 1</a>  <a href="#" id="fonts_group_2b">Show font group 2</a>

<fieldset class="groups" id="fonts_group_1" style="dispaly:none">
    <label style="font-family: Courier;">
        <input type="radio" name="font" value="Courier" />Courier</label>
    <label style="font-family: Verdana;">
        <input type="radio" name="font" value="Verdana" />Verdana</label>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="groups" id="fonts_group_2" style="dispaly:none">
    <label style="font-family: Arial;">
        <input type="radio" name="font" value="Arial" />Arial</label>
    <label style="font-family: Papyrus;">
        <input type="radio" name="font" value="Papyrus" />Papyrus</label>
</fieldset>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        $('a#fonts_group_1b').click(function() {
            $('.groups').hide();
            $('#fonts_group_1').show();
        }
        $('a#fonts_group_2b').click(function() {
            $('.groups').hide();
            $('#fonts_group_2').show();
        }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Impossible to answer, I have no idea what your question is. Please rephraze.

Comment: Please make your question more specific. What have you tried thus far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Try HiGoogleFonts. It lists all the fonts in a drop-down list with instant preview. https://github.com/saadqbal/HiGoogleFonts

Answer (score 0):

One of these should lead you down the right path.

- http://www.queness.com/post/212/10-jquery-and-non-jquery-javascript-rich-text-editors
- http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2008/12/20-excellent-free-rich-text-editors/

Comment: you have provided links for text editor..how come it is usefull to desghn font picker??

Comment: I thought they could help since these rich-text editors already have a font-picker included.  In most, you can even customize the fonts in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try to group radio buttons into fieldsets:

```
<fieldset id="fonts_group_1" style="dispaly:none">
    //your radiobuttons
</fieldset>
<fieldset id="fonts_group_2" style="dispaly:none">
    //your radiobuttons
</fieldset>
```

And you can use `$('#fonts_group_1').show();` in proper jquery script (for example in case when other radiobutton is checked).

--edit:

Here is complete code for you:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="fonts_group_1b">Show font group 1</a> <a href="#" id="fonts_group_2b">Show font group 2</a>

<fieldset class="groups" id="fonts_group_1" style="dispaly:none">
    <label style="font-family: Courier;">
        <input type="radio" name="font" value="Courier"/>Courier</label>
<label style="font-family: Verdana;">
        <input type="radio" name="font" value="Verdana"/>Verdana</label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="groups" id="fonts_group_2" style="dispaly:none">
    <label style="font-family: Arial;">
        <input type="radio" name="font" value="Arial"/>Arial</label>
    <label style="font-family: Papyrus;">
        <input type="radio" name="font" value="Papyrus"/>Papyrus</label>
</fieldset>
```

Script:

```
$(function() {

    $('a#fonts_group_1b').click(function() {
        $('.groups').hide();
        $('#fonts_group_1').show();
    });
    $('a#fonts_group_2b').click(function() {
        $('.groups').hide();
        $('#fonts_group_2').show();
    });

});
```

Comment: <fieldset> would be more semantically correct. http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/fieldset

Comment: can you please compleate your code.... i think your code works but i also need to know how to use  $('#fonts_group_1').show();    ???please compleate your code with "font1" and "font2" categories ....

Comment: I edited code on quick. You can improve script to be shorter, depending on the final alignment of fieldsets.

Comment: can we just modify the same code to create font picker like "flametext.com" or cooltext...???

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?  You can refactor the HTML to use radio buttons if you would rather.

http://www.fullfatcode.com/2011/04/10/jquery-font-selector-version-2/

Here is a demo of it.

http://www.fullfatcode.com/examples/jqfontselector/